# PayPal Express Checkout on behalf of a client

Tags: node.js, paypal

I've received permissions for Express Checkout from my client using the Permissions Service and I can generate the X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/).

I don't understand how can I call the SetExpressCheckout API on behalf of my client. I don't see the X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header mentioned in the [Express Checkout docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).